# Write to Struct offset using definition (C)

Tags: c, struct, syntax

I've got a struct that I can read from using the two definitions `IP_V(ip)` and `IP_HL(ip)` but I also need to write to them. What is the syntax for writing to the lower and higher bits in `ip_vhl` given a struct `struct pkt_ip ip;`?

```
struct pkt_ip
{
    uint8_t         ip_vhl;         /* header length, version */
    #define IP_V(ip)        (((ip)->ip_vhl & 0xf0) >> 4)
    #define IP_HL(ip)       ((ip)->ip_vhl & 0x0f)
    uint8_t         ip_tos;         /* type of service */
    #define IP_DSCP(ip)        (((ip)->ip_tos & 0xfc) >> 4)
    #define IP_ECN(ip)       ((ip)->ip_tos & 0x3f)
    uint16_t        ip_len;         /* total length */
    uint16_t        ip_id;          /* identification */
    uint16_t        ip_off;         /* fragment offset field */
    #define IP_DF 0x4000                    /* dont fragment flag */
    #define IP_MF 0x2000                    /* more fragments flag */
    #define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff               /* mask for fragmenting bits */
    uint8_t         ip_ttl;         /* time to live */
    uint8_t         ip_p;           /* protocol */
    uint16_t        ip_sum;         /* checksum */
    struct  in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;  /* source and dest address */
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do the bit manipulation on the `ip_vhl` field yourself.

To set the version:

```
header.ip_vhl = (header.ip_vhl & 0x0f) | ((new_version & 0xf) << 4);
```

to set the header length:

```
header.ip_vhl = (header.ip_vhl & 0xf0) | (new_length & 0xf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to use a value `myVal` ranging from `0x0..0x0f` either into the lower or into the higher nibble of `ip_vhl`. Then you can use the following statements:

```
ip_vhl = (ip_vhl & 0x0f) | ((myVal & 0x0f) << 4)

ip_vhl = (ip_vhl & 0xf0) | (myVal & 0x0f)
```